# System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher works if called from PowerShell but not if called from cmd.exe

Tags: scripting, powershell, active-directory, cmd, powershell-2.0

I wrote an script for PowerShell 1.0 (now using 2.0) that executes a search on my Active Directory. The code is the following:

```
$filter = "some filter"

$rootEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.SearchRoot = $rootEntry
$searcher.Filter = $filter
$searcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colResults = $searcher.FindAll()
```

After calling FindAll() method of the DirectorySearcher instance, I print the results to see what I got.

The thing is, if I start PowerShell.exe and call the script on the prompt I'm able to see results. But if I try to call it using cmd.exe using the same filter I don't see any results. FindAll() returns an empty result set.

I'm running this on a Windows 2003 Server. It did not came with PowerShell 1.0 so I downloaded it and installed it on the server. It does have .Net Framework 2.0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the server has SP2 then PowerShell 2.0 is supported. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: Yes thanks, I tried to install PowerShell 2.0 however it says I require .Net Framework 2.0 SP1. I would rather like not having to install anything on the costumer servers, but it is an option that I will keep in mind.

Comment: So I upgraded to 2.0 to see if that solves the issue. But I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: I'd just call it from PowerShell. I seldom use cmd.exe anymore. My comment was that there's little reason to use v1.0 now.

Comment: Ok yes I got you. Do you know if there is some context or environment settings that are preventing the DirectorySearcher from getting results? I mean, I don't specify anywhere the AD server ip-adress or credentials, so can it be possible that when called from cmd.exe the script uses incorrect values?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I would suggest retagging as powershell-v2.0; that might get more people to look at the question.

Comment: I tagged again to powershell-v2.0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might also check out http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx - that's what we use at work. They make AD very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working by doing two things:

1. Upgrade to PowerShell 2.0.
2. Run with -File option.

So the command was run like this:

```
>>powershell -file ./script.ps1 "dn" "uid"
```

I'm not sure what the difference between the -File and -Command options are (does anyone?) but it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By defaul your $rootEntry point on the root of you local AD i you are running on a server, and this with the credetial of the current process. you don't show what is your filter and how you use your result.

Here is a small sample of an ADSI search from PowerShell

```
Clear-Host
# ADSI Bind with current process credentials
#$dn = [adsi] "LDAP://192.168.30.200:389/dc=dom,dc=fr"
# ADSI Bind with specific credentials
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.183.138:389/dc=societe,dc=fr","administrateur@societe.fr","test.2011")


# Look for users

$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$rc = $Rech.filter = "((objectCategory=person))"
$rc = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");  
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ipphone");  
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName"); # Your attribute

$liste = $Rech.findall()
```

Comment: Thank you. Added both the LDAP Url and credentials, but still having the issue. Do I need to import some module or some profile? I want to get user group membership information, so I use this filter (|(member=$dn)(member=$uid)). After searching, I just print groups distinguished name.

Comment: Please can you give the exact command you write at CMD.EXE prompt

Comment: Sure, this is it: **>>powershell -command ./script.ps1 "dn" "uid"**

Comment: I was on the right way, -file allow you execute a .PS1 file, it handle arguments in the right way wich was not working well in PowerShell V1.0 -command simulate a command quite as you where in Powershell but to start a script you'd better use "invoke-expression" **powershell -command "& {invoke-expression '.\script.ps1 \"dn\" \"uid\" '}**